# Laravel unit testing mock eloquent's query scope method

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mocking, eloquent

I would like to mock model's scope method, is it possible?

Here is the scenario:

**Order model:**

```
public function scopeForUser($query) // query scope method which should be mocked
{

    return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
}
```

**User model:**

```
public function getOrders()
{

    $orders = $this->orders(); // Returns Eloquent object(HasMany) 

    $orders->forUser(); // I would like to mock forUser() method

    return $orders->get();
}
```

**TestCase:**

```
public function testGetUsersOrders()
{
    $userOrders = Order::where('user_id', 1);

    // Mock Order's forUser method
    $this->mock =  Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Order'); // ?? I can't mock HasMany object, can I?
    $this->app->instance('Order', $this->mock);

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('forUser')->once()->andReturn($userOrders->get());

    $result = $this->user->getOrders();
    $this->assertEquals($userOrders->get(), $result);

}
```

*This is simplified example.*

Answer (score 0):

It is probably too late for an suggestion but just for future reference:

```
$hasMany = Mockery::mock->shouldReceive('getResults')
                        ->andReturn($userOrders->get())
                        ->mock();
$this->mock->shouldReceive('forUser')->once()->andReturn($hasMany);
```

But your code does not really make much sense to me neither.

In your example:

```
public function getOrders()
{

    $orders = $this->orders(); // Returns Eloquent object(HasMany) 

    $orders->forUser(); // if the above code returns HasMany, Are you trying
                        // to call 'hasMany->forUser()' ?
                        // And even after it is mocked properly and returned
                        // you the '$userOrders->get()'.  It won't do anything
                        // because the result is not kept anywhere and it is 
                        // not used any where neither.

    return $orders->get();  // And then you called 'return $orders->get()'
                            // which has nothing to do with your
                            // '$orders->forUser();'.  It will execute the
                            // $orders you got from the very first line.


}
```